# Album created in Mac Big Sur's Photos app not appearing in iPhone Photos app

Tags: iphone, mac, photos

I have created an album in the Mac's Photos app. Uploaded photos to that album (taken from Digital Camera). But I neither see photos nor album in my iPhone's photos app.

How to make the newly created album with photos appear on the iPhone. I see iCloud photos syncing is enabled in both iPhone and Mac. I can see photos taken on iPhone in Mac's Photos app.

Comment: if you access icloud.com, do the photos show up there?

Comment: Is it a smart album?

Comment: @EzekielElin is photos and the album shows up in iCloud

Comment: @fsb No, it is not a smart album.

Comment: Looks like restarting iPhone will sync up the new album and photos. But let me try to create one more album and see how it works.